# Why I got only 2 reputation for upvote

Tags: support, reputation, answers, voting, up-votes

Yesterday I faced one issue, I don't know wether it's an issue or my fault of  understanding.

Here is answered one question  [Can GWT handle Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175946/can-gwt-handle-java-swing/16176035#16176035)

Answer accepted and got 4 up votes. Still reputation is (32+15=47) only.So for one up vote I got  2 rep only.

I don't want my reputation back, I'm just curious.

[image]

Comment: Why downvote?? please bare me i am very less experienced in Meta.Thanks for your support.

Comment: [Downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for the clarification  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations. You just reached to daily reputation cap. Yesterday, you got 20 upvotes, and a downvote so you had 198 reputation from upvotes and then you got an upvote which gave you remaining 2 reputation.

See this calculation below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks hims :) jakkas.